# Converting Nested Dict in list to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to organize data into a DataFrame, the data was originally in the form of:

```
{'candles': [{'open': 295.43, 'high': 295.47, 'low': 295.32, 'close': 295.4, 'volume': 15483, 'datetime': 1589972400000}, {'open': 295.35, 'high': 295.51, 'low': 295.35, 'close': 295.51, 'volume': 14187, 'datetime': 1589972460000}, {'open': 295.49, 'high': 295.49, 'low': 295.46, 'close': 295.46, 'volume': 3792, 'datetime': 1589972520000}, {'open': 295.44, 'high': 295.47, 'low': 295.39, 'close': 295.41, 'volume': 6121, 'datetime': 1589972580000}
```

I want to format it so my index is the date (daily) and my only column is 'close'.  I'm newish to python and having a lot of trouble getting this to format correctly, this is what I have so far:

```
SPY_close=td_client.get_price_history('SPY')
SPY_close=pd.DataFrame(SPY_close)
SPY_close=pd.DataFrame.drop(SPY_close, columns=['empty', 'symbol'])
```

which gave me:

```
    candles
0   {'open': 295.43, 'high': 295.47, 'low': 295.32, 'close': 295.4, 'volume': 15483, 'datetime': 1589972400000}
1   {'open': 295.35, 'high': 295.51, 'low': 295.35, 'close': 295.51, 'volume': 14187, 'datetime': 1589972460000}
2   {'open': 295.49, 'high': 295.49, 'low': 295.46, 'close': 295.46, 'volume': 3792, 'datetime': 1589972520000}
3   {'open': 295.44, 'high': 295.47, 'low': 295.39, 'close': 295.41, 'volume': 6121, 'datetime': 1589972580000}
4   {'open': 295.41, 'high': 295.46, 'low': 295.38, 'close': 295.38, 'volume': 10295, 'datetime': 1589972640000}
```

I also tried:

`SPYdf = pd.DataFrame(SPY['candles'])
SPYdf['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(SPYdf['datetime'], unit='ms')
SPYdf.head()`

I'm getting `KeyError: 'Candles'` with this one

I tried multiple solutions to similar problems on here and none of them have worked, but I feel it should be fairly simple to do. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `SPY_close_df = pd.DataFrame(data=SPY_close["candles"])` ? `I'm getting KeyError: 'Candles' with this one` Based on what you shared, that shouldn't be happening. Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
d = {'candles': [{'open': 295.43, 'high': 295.47, 'low': 295.32, 'close': 295.4, 'volume': 15483, 'datetime': 1589972400000}, {'open': 295.35, 'high': 295.51, 'low': 295.35, 'close': 295.51, 'volume': 14187, 'datetime': 1589972460000}, {'open': 295.49, 'high': 295.49, 'low': 295.46, 'close': 295.46, 'volume': 3792, 'datetime': 1589972520000}, {'open': 295.44, 'high': 295.47, 'low': 295.39, 'close': 295.41, 'volume': 6121, 'datetime': 1589972580000}

In [1864]: df = pd.DataFrame(d['candles']).set_index('datetime')    
In [1865]: df
Out[1865]: 
                open   high    low  close  volume
datetime                                         
1589972400000 295.43 295.47 295.32 295.40   15483
1589972460000 295.35 295.51 295.35 295.51   14187
1589972520000 295.49 295.49 295.46 295.46    3792
1589972580000 295.44 295.47 295.39 295.41    6121
```

Comment: `candles` is the main key in the dictionary you shared. Check my updated answer.

Comment: This worked great, initially I accidentally grabbed the wrong data label when I substituted it for d. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `json_normalize` or `from_dict`:

```
d = {'candles': [{'open': 295.43, 'high': 295.47, 'low': 295.32, 'close': 295.4, 'volume': 15483, 'datetime': 1589972400000}, {'open': 295.35, 'high': 295.51, 'low': 295.35, 'close': 295.51, 'volume': 14187, 'datetime': 1589972460000}, {'open': 295.49, 'high': 295.49, 'low': 295.46, 'close': 295.46, 'volume': 3792, 'datetime': 1589972520000}, {'open': 295.44, 'high': 295.47, 'low': 295.39, 'close': 295.41, 'volume': 6121, 'datetime': 1589972580000}]}
df = pd.json_normalize(d['candles'])
print(df)

    open    high     low   close  volume       datetime
0  295.43  295.47  295.32  295.40   15483  1589972400000
1  295.35  295.51  295.35  295.51   14187  1589972460000
2  295.49  295.49  295.46  295.46    3792  1589972520000
3  295.44  295.47  295.39  295.41    6121  1589972580000
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['candles'])
```

Comment: Did you copy this exact code without any changes and run it?

Comment: I apoligize, when I substituted my data label for d I used the wrong one leading to the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
d = {'candles': [{'open': 295.43, 'high': 295.47, 'low': 295.32, 
                  'close': 295.4, 'volume': 15483, 'datetime': 1589972400000}, 
                 {'open': 295.35, 'high': 295.51, 'low': 295.35, 
                  'close': 295.51, 'volume': 14187, 'datetime': 1589972460000}, 
                 {'open': 295.49, 'high': 295.49, 'low': 295.46,
                  'close': 295.46, 'volume': 3792, 'datetime': 1589972520000}, 
                 {'open': 295.44, 'high': 295.47, 'low': 295.39, 
                  'close': 295.41, 'volume': 6121, 'datetime': 1589972580000}]
    }
pd.DataFrame(d['candles'])
```

Output:

```
     open    high     low   close  volume       datetime
0  295.43  295.47  295.32  295.40   15483  1589972400000
1  295.35  295.51  295.35  295.51   14187  1589972460000
2  295.49  295.49  295.46  295.46    3792  1589972520000
3  295.44  295.47  295.39  295.41    6121  1589972580000
```